# get value from updated row

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to get the new rating from an UPDATE statement in java

```
int userID = 99;

String sql = "UPDATE table SET rating=rating+1 WHERE user_REF="+userID;
statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I can just do another SELECT statement, but isn't there a better way to retrieve the value or row while updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL:

```
$query1 = 'UPDATE `table` SET rating = (@rating:= rating) + 1 WHERE id = 1';
$query2 = 'select @rating';
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, No, there is no way to do this with ANSI standard SQL.

You have three options:

1) Do it in two queries - the update, then the select

2) Create a stored procedure that will execute the update and then return the select

3) Use a DB-specific extension, such as the PostgreSQL RETURNING clause

Note that options 2) and 3) are database-specific.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the replies everybody, i ended up doing it like this:

```
int userID = 99;

String sql = "SELECT id, rating FROM table WHERE user_REF="+userID;
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

rs.first();
float oldRating = rs.getFloat("rating");
float newRating = oldRating +1;

rs.updateFloat("rating", newRating);
rs.updateRow();

return newRating;
```

that way it (or at least seems so) does only one query to find the correct row, or am i wrong?

Comment: this is wrong. You're still doing two queries... one to select the old rating, and one to update to the new rating, and on top of that, by not doing 'rating = rating +1' in SQL, you've introduced a race condition into your script. What if two users execute this script at the same time? They'll both select the old rating, and both update the value to the old rating plus one. Doing it inside of SQL the way my answer provided will ensure race conditions are avoided.

Comment: great. Thanks a lot for the infos, i'll do it your way.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL there is RETURNING clause

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-update.html

Comment: thanks, but i forgot to mention that i'm using mySQL. It doesn't seem to have that clause

Answer (score 0):

Be cautious that most solutions are database dependent (Whether or not you want database independence in your application ofcourse matters).

Also one other solution you could try is to write a procedure and execute it as follows

```
my_package.updateAndReturnRating(refId, cursor record).
```

Of course this may/may not make the solution itself complicated but worth an "evaluation" atleast.